# Why isn't my PSBT considered complete after walletprocesspsbt and finalizepsbt?

Tags: bitcoin-core, bip174-psbt

I created a transaction using `createrawtransaction` spending a UTXO that I own the keys to and then converted it to PSBT using `converttopsbt`, then I used `walletprocesspsbt` and `finalizepsbt`. After `finalizepsbt`, my "complete" value is false.

Is there a way to get more details on why it's not considered completed?

Thanks,
Francois

Comment: Have you tried using `analyzepsbt` to see what it thinks the next step is? You could also use `decodepsbt` to inspect it and see if there is anything missing.

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I missed the method analyzepsbt.

Comment: Any updates here?

Comment: @Andrewchow: given that Francois was asking how to figure out more details, I think your comment would be a great answer.

Comment: Hi Pieter, Andrew, Murch, I had a weird bug where after importing a private key into my wallet, when doing the walletprocesspsbt, it did not sign my psbt transaction. I reloaded the wallet and was able to successfully sign the transaction. Are the wallet private keys cached on load? It's also possible that I was the problem :). The analyzepsbt gave me the clue to investigate my issue. Thanks for the help guys!

Answer (score 2):

To get more details about the next steps for a PSBT, you can use the `analyzepsbt` RPC. Additionally, `decodepsbt` will tell you what information is in a PSBT so you can use that to inspect the PSBT to learn what is missing.