# walletprocesspsbt rpc not signing psbt tx

Tags: json-rpc, signature, bitcoin-cli, bip174-psbt, sendrawtransaction

After extensive regtest testing I've been unable to reproduce this issue.

This is a gist to regtest psbt commands that do work.
https://gist.github.com/miketwenty1/ecb9acdbca858878f1856b75493fef4c

wpkh() + tr() are the descriptor inputs used for each and in the same format.

The step on main chain where I'm getting stuck is when I try to do a `walletprocesspsbt`.

I will get a `"complete": false` instead of `"complete": true`

When I run `analyzepsbt` It says I'm missing a signature.

```
{
  "inputs": [
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "updater"
    },
    {
      "has_utxo": true,
      "is_final": false,
      "next": "signer",
      "missing": {
        "signatures": [
          "<some_hex_sig>"
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "estimated_vsize": 204,
  "estimated_feerate": 0.00010078,
  "fee": 0.00002056,
  "next": "updater"
}
```

This is confusing for me, because when I run `./bitcoin-cli listunspent`
Both of my UTXO's are

- `"spendable": true`
- `"solvable": true`
- `"safe": true`

## Question:

What are the next steps in troubleshooting why my wallet can't sign this this psbt transaction?

**Note**:
This looks like a similar issue that never really had a conclusion:
[Why isn't my PSBT considered complete after walletprocesspsbt and finalizepsbt?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/97130/why-isnt-my-psbt-considered-complete-after-walletprocesspsbt-and-finalizepsbt)

Comment: In my frustration I followed what francois said he did, I just reimported and now everything magically works.. the unspent utxo's have not changed. I'm thinking this is a bug.